# What does string index out of range mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to make a reversi game using python. this is the code for a blank board

```
   #reversi
import random
import sys
board = range(9)
def char_range(start, end, step=1):
    for char in range(ord(start), ord(end), step):
        yield char
def drawBoard(board):
    ###this prints out the board
    HLINE = ' +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+'
    VLINE = ' | | | | | | | | |'
    print('  a b c d e f g h')
    print(HLINE)
    for y in range(8):
        print(y+1, end = '|.|')
        for x in char_range('a','h'):
            print('| %s' %(board[x][y]), end='.')
        print('|')
        print(HLINE)
def resetBoard(board):
    #blanks out the board
    for x in char_range('a', 'h'):
        for y in range(8):
            board[x][y] = '.'
    #starters
    board[c][3] = 'X'
    board[c][4] = 'O'
    board[d][3] = 'O'
    board[d][4] = 'X'
def getNewBoard():
    #new board
    board = []
    for i in range(9):
        board.append([' '] * 9)
    return board
getNewBoard()
drawBoard(board)
resetBoard(board)
```

for some reason when i execute it i get this message:

```
 File "C:\Users\Larry\Desktop\test.py", line 18, in drawBoard
print('| %s' % (board[x][y]), end='.')
IndexError: string index out of range
```

what does this mean.  do i need to change

```
char_range()
```

or the

```
 print('| %s' % (board[x][y]), end='.')
```

Comment: It means the string is not as big as you think and you can't index after its end.

Answer (score 0):

As wim commented, a dict is often a perfectly fine way to implement a board like this

```
def getNewBoard():
    #new board
    board = {}
    for x in range(8): # or x in 'abcdefgh': if you prefer
        for y in range(8):
            board[x, y] = ' '
    return board
```

And don't forget to assign the board to `board`

```
board = getNewBoard()
```

Comment: @derpyherp, dunno are you doing something like `board[ord('a')]`??

Comment: print('| %s' %(board[x][y]), end='.')
KeyError: 97

Comment: @derpyherpy: you should be doing `board[x, y]` not `board[x][y]` following gnibbler's code.

Comment: @derpyherp, first decide which method you are going to use - letters or numbers. At the moment you are using a sort of hybrid: the ordinal  values of the letters